# c# lambda expression - add delegate results to generic list

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, lambda

**Question:** I have just wrote my first code using c# lambda expressions. It works, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.  Any recommendations on a better way to do the lambda expression?  It seems odd to have numerous lines of code in the expression like I do below.

**Background:** I have a generic list of delegates.  Each delegate function returns an enum value indicating what happened in the function.  Upon evaluation of the delegate, I need to add the enum to a List if it was not a specific enum value.

**Disclaimer:** Code here is very generic, the real code actually does stuff in the delegates to determine the return value!

---

```
class Class1
{
    public enum WhatHappened
    {
        ThingA,
        ThingB,
        Nothing
    }

    private delegate WhatHappened del();

    public static List<WhatHappened> DoStuff()
    {
        List<del> CheckValues = new List<del>();

        List<WhatHappened> returnValue = new List<WhatHappened> { };

        CheckValues.Add(delegate { return method1(); });
        CheckValues.Add(delegate { return method2(); });

        CheckValues.ForEach(x =>
        {
            WhatHappened wh = x();
            if (wh != WhatHappened.Nothing)
                returnValue.Add(wh);
        });

        return returnValue;

    }

    private static WhatHappened method1()
    {
        return WhatHappened.Nothing;
    }

    private static WhatHappened method2()
    {
        return WhatHappened.ThingA;
    }

}
```

**Note:**  I originally had the lambda like adding all the items (see below), then removing the ones I didn't want (WhatHappened.Nothing).

```
CheckValues.ForEach(x => returnValue.Add(x()));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, a few suggestions:

- Don't call your delegate `del`. In this case, I'd use `Func<WhatHappened>` - but if you *do* want to declare your own delegate type, give it a more descriptive name, and obey the .NET naming conventions.
- Instead of using anonymous methods to add to `CheckValues`, you can just use:

  ```
  CheckValues.Add(method1);
  CheckValues.Add(method2);
  ```

  The compiler will convert the method groups into delegates.
- I'd recommend not using Pascal case for a local variable name to start with.
- Your collection initializer for `returnValues` isn't really doing anything for you - just call the `List<T>` constructor as normal, or use my code below which doesn't require a local variable to start with.
- If your list *really* only has two delegates in it, I'd just call them separately. It's a lot simpler.
- Otherwise you can indeed use LINQ as Jared suggests, but I'd do it slightly differently:

  ```
  return CheckValues.Select(x => x())
                    .Where(wh => wh != WhatHappened.Nothing)
                    .ToList();
  ```

EDIT: As suggested, here's the full example. It's not quite the same as Denis's though... I've made a couple of changes :)

```
public static List<WhatHappened> DoStuff()
{
    var functions = new List<Func<WhatHappened>> { Method1, Method2 };

    return functions.Select(function => function())
                    .Where(result => result != WhatHappened.Nothing)
                    .ToList();
}
```

(I'm assuming that `method1` and `method2` have been renamed to fit the naming convention. Of course in real life I'm sure they'd have more useful names anyway...)

Comment: I agree with your suggestions, but I think you took the example a little too literally.  In the example code I didn't spend time with naming conventions.  The real code has more descriptive names.

Comment: If you give an example of your code, and ask us what we would do differently, how are we meant to know the difference between mistakes you *do* know about and mistakes you *don't* know about?

Comment: I think the main thing is to use the existing Func rather than your own delegate type.  Then the naming is moot.

Comment: damn Jon, you beat me to it AND you manage to give better explanations. Does your keyboard read your mind or something ? :)

Comment: Lots of great advice in this answer. I would suggest combining it with the completely rewritten example from Denis Troller's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can go lambda all the way by chaining Select (map) and Where (filter) instead of multiple FOR loops and IF statements

```
// get results from the list of functions
var results = CheckValues.Select(x => x());

// filter out only the relevant ones.
var returnValues = results.Where(x => x != WhatHappened.Nothing);
```

Basically, you should think more **[declaratively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming)** instead of **[imperatively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming)** when work ing with lambdas. It'll help you write more elegant code.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply use Linq, but that's just me:

```
public static List<WhatHappened> DoStuff()
{
    List<del> CheckValues = new List<del>();

    List<WhatHappened> returnValue = new List<WhatHappened>();

    CheckValues.Add(method1);
    CheckValues.Add(method2);

    return CheckValues
               .Select(dlg => dlg())
               .Where( res => res != WhatHappened.Nothing)
               .ToList();
}
```

Note that you can also use Func  instead of declaring a Delegate type if you want, but that's less terse in that case.
Also, I'd return an `IEnumerable<WhatHappened>` instead of a List, but it's all about the context.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit more idiomatic to write the following instead of using the delegate keyword.  It doesn't change the underlying functionality though.

```
CheckValues.Add( () => method1() );
```

Also, I find it more readable to rewrite the ForEach as the following

```
CheckValues = CheckValues.
  Select(x => x()).
  Where(wh => wh != WhatHappened.Nothing ). 
  ToList();
```

Comment: That won't compile unless you've got a ForEach extension method. I also like having my dots at the start of lines :)

Comment: @Jon, I'm so used to my custom LINQ methods that I forget they don't exist by default.  Updated to avoid extension methods i don't own.  I honestly go back and forth on dot before or dot after. My normal preference is dot before. But some languages I use require character to be after (PowerShell and VB.Net) so I drift back and forth ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, based on the example, it looks fine. You could refactor even more by replacing:

```
CheckValues.Add(delegate { return method1(); });
CheckValues.Add(delegate { return method2(); });
```

with:

```
CheckValues.Add(() => WhatHappened.Nothing);
CheckValues.Add(() => WhatHappened.ThingA);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LINQ-free solution:

```
return CheckValues
    .ConvertAll<WhatHappened>(x => x())
    .FindAll(y => y != WhatHappened.Nothing);
```

**caveat**

This is not the most performant solution, as it would iterate twice.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fathom the purpose of the code.. however here goes.
Used delegate chaining 
**Update:** and picked up some Enumerable goodness from Jon n Jared's posts

```
private delegate WhatHappened WhatHappenedDelegate();

public static List<WhatHappened> DoStuff()
{
    WhatHappenedDelegate delegateChain = null;
    delegateChain += method1;
    delegateChain += method2;

    return delegateChain.GetInvocationList() 
            .Select(x => (WhatHappened) x.DynamicInvoke())
            .Where( wh => (wh != WhatHappened.Nothing))
            .ToList<WhatHappened>();
}
```